# how to fix Invalid image size specified on aforge.net

Tags: c#, exception, image-processing, aforge

i have a project using aforge.net, and i kind of facing a problem.
i always got Invalid image size specified exception, and i don't know why.
if anybody could help me, it would be great...

here's my code:

```
private void videoSourcePlayer_NewFrame(object sender, ref Bitmap image)
    {

        string filepath = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\plat.JPG";
        Bitmap imageContoh = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filepath, true));

        UnmanagedImage unImage = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(imageContoh);
        UnmanagedImage clone = unImage.Clone();
        ResizeBilinear resize = new ResizeBilinear(512, 512);
        imageUntukDiproses = resize.Apply(clone);
        if (imageUntukDiproses != null)
        {
            //Preprosessing gambar
            PreProcessing pre = new PreProcessing(imageUntukDiproses);
            UnmanagedImage hasilPre = pre.HasilPreProcessing;
            UnmanagedImage grayscale = pre.GambarGrayscale;
            //penentuan lokasi plat
            PenentuLokasiPlat plat = new PenentuLokasiPlat(hasilPre, grayscale);

            //ekstraksi plat
            UnmanagedImage platfix = plat.PlatKendaraan;
            plat.Drawing(image);

            //tampilan histogram untuk hasil preprosessing
            histogram1.Values = plat.Hishorlogic;
            histogram3.Values = plat.Hisverlogic;


            if (platfix != null)
            {
                SegmentasiHuruf segmen = new SegmentasiHuruf(platfix);
                byte[,] ciripertama = segmen.Karakter[1];
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { dataGridView1.DataSource = new ArrayDataView(ciripertama); }));

                //Menampilkan image hasil
            }

        }
        Bitmap gambar = imageUntukDiproses.ToManagedImage();
        image = gambar;
    }
```

on the exception i see image is null..

Comment: Where do you get the exception? `resize.Apply(clone)`? What kind of exception is thrown, and exactly what message do you get? The `ResizeBilinear` filter supports pixel formats *8bppIndexed*, *24bppRgb*, *32bppRgb* and *32bppArgb*, is your `imageContoh` in any of these formats? If not, you could use the `Image.Clone(Bitmap, PixelFormat)` method to change pixel format before making it an `UnmanagedImage`.

Comment: yeah, i get exception in resize.Apply(clone). and my imageContoh is in these formats.
i somehow managed to get it fixed. i re-installed the library and retyped the ResizeBilinear instance. and it worked. i don't know why. maybe i'm just lucky...